# Intel's oneapi C compiler not producing debug information

Tags: debugging, gdb, icc, intel-oneapi, intel-gdb

I have some simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hello world\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I would like to debug it so I compile like so

```
icl.exe /Z7 /debug:all /Od main.c -o test.exe
```

I then run the debugger

```
gdb-oneapi
```

but when I load the file I get the following error:

```
(gdb) file test.exe
Reading symbols from test.exe...
(No debugging symbols found in test.exe)
```

Am I missing some important flag?

Comment: `-o test` is not the same filename as `file test.exe`.  Probably `test.exe` is left over from an earlier build.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Though when I use -o test.exe the problem persists

Comment: Does it help to run `gdb-oneapi test.exe`?  That shouldn't be any different from using `file` within GDB, but IDK.  What do other tools say?  I was going to suggest `readelf -a`, but a `.exe` isn't an ELF.  Can you confirm that GDB version works with debug-info from GCC or clang `-g`?  Does `icl` support a GCC-style `-g` option to include debug info?